# (Nginx) Serve up index file with MD5 hash

Tags: nginx, deployment, webserver, frontend

Hi I was trying to figure out how to serve up an index.html file with an MD5 hash in the filename.

> eg: index-13e5cb2.html (where the 13e5cb2 part keeps changing for
>   every deployment)

I'm guessing i need to configure nginx to match using a regular expression but am not sure how this can be done.

Can anybody help me figure out what I need to add to my conf file?

Currently all I have is

```
server {
  listen 80 default deferred;

  server_name myapp.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  root /home/testuser/client/;

  index index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```